# How to elegantly access thread-safe collection and use AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two methods, `ProcessQueue` and `AddToQueue`, which happen on different threads.  Sometimes I will attempt to Process the Queue before an item is added to a queue, at which point I want to wait for an item to be added to a queue.  I also want to make sure that I will never get a situation where I wait, *after* the Queue is evaluated as being empty and then *after* the Queue is added to on a different thread.  Below is my attempt at doing this, but a deadlock is created because the Auto Reset Event waits with a lock still in force.

There has to be a more elegant way of doing this.  Any suggestions?

```
private readonly object m_Locker = new object();
private readonly Queue<int> m_Queue = new Queue<int>();
private readonly AutoResetEvent m_AutoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

void ProcessQueue()
{
  lock (m_Locker)
  {
    if (m_Queue.Count == 0)
    {
      // nothing is happening, so wait for it to happen
      m_AutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Processed {0}", m_Queue.Dequeue());
}

// on another thread
void AddToQueue(int i)
{
  lock (m_Locker) 
  {
    m_Queue.Enqueue(i);
    m_AutoResetEvent.Set();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is that you keep the queue locked in while you're waiting for the event.**

This way the other process can't add to the queue because it is already locked. Try this:

```
int value = 0;

while (true)
{
    lock (m_Locker)
    {
        if (m_Queue.Count > 0)
        {
            value = m_Queue.Dequeue();
            break;
        }
    }

    m_AutoResetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

With the example above, you also dequeue in the lock, so you are sure that no other thread has a chance to dequeue between the moment you waited and the moment that you check the queue actually had an item.

Comment: Couldn't this set up a situation, though where you unlock m_Locker, on another thread, it adds an element to a queue and m_AutoResetEvent.Set(), then does m_AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() on the original thread?

Comment: If the `Set` happens before the `WaitOne`, the `WaitOne` continues immediately. That's exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: Got it.  I got confused about auto reset event there.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

You must release the lock on the queue `m_locker` before you issue the wait.  You could do that manually with a `Monitor`, reacquire and recheck after your wait is satisfied. This way you only hold the lock while you are checking for non-zero element count.

If you are on .Net 4 you can use `BlockingCollection<T>` or `ConcurrentQueue<T>` instead, from [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).  There's really no reason to build this by hand any more.

This code won't work if you have > 1 concurrent consumer - you'd need a `Semaphore` instead of `AutoResetEvent` in that case to ensure the correct number of consumers get signaled.

Since you can't use .Net 4, there are guidelines for this scenario [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f%28VS.80%29.aspx).  Note that the comments on that article include some approaches you can use to make this bulletproof.

> The following example demonstrates
>   thread synchronization between the
>   primary thread and two worker threads
>   using the lock keyword, and the
>   AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent
>   classes.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of these classes.  I'm using .NET 3.5 but am using the Task Parallel library as a dll.  My sutation keeps me from following your advice since my real example includes more than one collection (a Dictionary of Queues).

Comment: So I have to (1) look up to see if the dictionary has a queue, and (2) look at whether the queue has items.

Comment: @Michael - this might be useful then: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Brian, yes, that's covered in the comments. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @Steve: Nah, I jumped the gun with my first comment as I thought I was responding to someone else.  Clearly, you already know about the `AutoResetEvent` problem :)

Comment: Yes but worth pointing this out anyway.  No guarantee OP would read those comments.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: @Steve: By the way, I should mention that your answers regarding multithreaded programming in general tend to be very good. I often upvote your answers even though you may not realize it. Just thought I'd pass along a friendly compliment :)

Comment: @Brian - thanks for that.  OT, it seems like the demand for threading expertise is going up lately.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is textbook deadlock example. The bottom line is you don't want to enter the Wait state on your AutoResetEvent while locking on m_locker in the `ProcessQueue` function.

Also, note that the generic Queue implementation in .NET is not thread-safe so you should also guard access to the `Dequeue` call in `ProcessQueue`.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you want to do:

```
// no lock up here
while (true)
{
  // nothing is happening, so wait for it to happen
  m_AutoResetEvent.WaitOne();

  lock (m_locker)  
  {
  // ProcessTheQueue(); // process the queue after the reset event is Set 
  }
}
```

and then:

```
lock (m_Locker) 
  {
    m_Queue.Enqueue(i);
  }
    m_AutoResetEvent.Set();
```

?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4 the new `BlockingCollection<T>` provides the most elegant way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Why bothering with the AutoResetEvent in the first place?

When you call the Process function, if it doesn't find anything than it should exit. I don't see the point in waiting since you'll probably just call it again after a while...

Comment: The simplified example begs that question, but my requirements are more complex and involve one thread processing a list and verifying that those events occurred on another thread.